# WPF C# NULL exception on combobox selection change

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

This is selection changed event :

```
private void cbUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectedUser = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
    GetUserInformation();
}
```

`GetUserInformation` is just selecting password from database. Users are deleted from the database and then the following refreshes the `ComboBox` items:

```
public void FillComboBox()
{
    cbUsers.ItemsSource = null;
    HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();
    var _UserName = (from d in db.users select d.username).ToList();
    cbUsers.ItemsSource = _UserName;
}

HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();

var _UserID = (from d in db.users where d.username == cbUsers.Text select d.id).SingleOrDefault();

user u = db.users.Single(p => p.id == _UserID);
db.users.DeleteOnSubmit(u);
db.SubmitChanges();
cbUsers.ItemsSource = null;
cbUsers.Text = null;
FillComboBox();
```

When using this last method it gives such error:

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The error falls on this line of the `FillComboBox` method:

```
SelectedUser = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that `SelectedItem` is `null` and therefore you're calling `ToString` on nothing.

Consider trying this:

```
if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem != null)
{
    SelectedUser = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

However, doesn't your `ComboBox` have an identifier? This can allow you to refrain from unnecessary conversions with `as`:

```
if (myComboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    SelectedUser = myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that `sender` might not be a `ComboBox`.

A problem of using an `as` operator without a `null` check is you get a `NullReferenceException` instead of a `InvalidCastException` which is more appropriate

Use an explicit cast instead e.g. `((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();` if you are sure `sender` is a `ComboBox`; otherwise check for `null` before usage.

Comment: If you are _sure_ of the type, then what does it matter which you use? Also, the `sender` _will_ be the control that raised the event, and hence a `ComboBox` in this case.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment Personally, readability of the intentions of the developer. Also, my interpretation was that the `as` operator was optimal over an explicit cast if using with a null check. Correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I actually overlooked the `SelectedItem` call which is is most likely to be the source of the error. However the method can still be called by anyone which does not guarantee that `sender` is a `ComboBox`

Comment: @sjyw: The caller _could_ very well be something other than the `ComboBox` (though it really shouldn't be!), you are of course correct there, but in this instance, all other things being equal, I give the OP the benefit of _that_ doubt. If the OP has code calling event handlers, then there is a bigger problem than the one posted here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is probably getting called when there is no `SelectedItem`.

I would write this as:

```
private void cbUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var usersComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (usersComboBox.SelectedItem == null) return;

    SelectedUser = usersComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    GetUserInformation();
}
```

Here you are expecting that sender is always a ComboBox, so I would use a cast instead of `as`.  The exception will let you know if your assumption is wrong.

This will just skip your code if the event handler is called without a selected item.